# Javaservice - Could not find the service class

Tags: java, java-service-wrapper

I am trying to install a simple java application as a windows service using javaservice.exe.

Below is my install command:

```
@"D:\Test\scripts\Windows\service\bin\Test Service.exe" -install "Test Service"
 "D:\Test\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll" -jar "-Djava.class.path=test.jar" -start "com.test.TestServerCLI" -method "main" -params -eSTART -dmyDB -mmem -uSA -i9001 -out "D:\Test\log\Test Service_service.log" -current "D:\Test\bin" -manual
```

The TestServerCLI class file is under D:\Test\bin\com\test and jre is installed at D:\Test.

Whenever I run the service from Windows Services console I get a dialog box saying -

> The Test Service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some
>   services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services
>   or programs.

The windows event log says -

> Could not find the service class.

Event ID: 4096

I am running JRE 1.7.0_02 on Windows7 32-bit machine. The Javaservice version is 2.0.10.0.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked. The test.jar was not presentt in the specified classpath. I added the jar to my classpath and now it works.

Comment: For me most of the times this error is seen due to some of the jars not included in classpath. I encountered it again and found out the same reason. But now something interesting, I am getting an event log: The Java Virtual Machine has exited with a code of 2, the service is being stopped. Where to get jvm exit codes from?